# ActiveStorage How to convert image before upload to S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I configured active storage to upload `has_one_attached :image` to Amazon S3.

```
product.image.attach(io: open(img_url), filename: "file.jpg")
```

But I want to optimize images: compress them or convert to .webp

I have [mini-magick gem](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) which i can use to modify images.

**So can I dynamically modify image from url before uploading to Amazon?**

Or all can I do is to save image from url, process it and then do `attach`? (It is so slow when I have millions of images)

Comment: I never tried, but maybe you can consider to use a lambda function for doing the job?

Answer (score 0):

According to ActiveStorage, it supports transformation, so you could try using https://github.com/janko/image_processing with mini magick or libvips convert method to transform the image before saving it. Or at least that's what i'm trying to do atm.
If i manage to do it I'll post it here.
Good luck

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Comment: @supersaidso Damn it was so long ago, I no longer have access to the code since i switched companies. But from what i can recall no. We still ended up uploading the whole image to the s3. And then from the frontend we used a library to load the image as webp. I figure if nothing works you can upload all images and then run a cronjob or task that night while you sleep that does the transformation. I haven't used rails for almost a year now sorry.